# Converting VTK point dataset of scalar values to a smooth surface

Tags: visualization

Does Paraview or Visit have any filters to draw a smooth surface for a set of points?

Answer (score 1):

In Paraview you can try the following :

- Delaunay2D (for creating a surface - see http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Filtering/Delaunay2D )
- Smooth
- LoopSubdivision (will also create new cells / new points)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked for filters in Paraview or VisIT. But, you could use another open source tool to reconstruct the surface first, such as [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)